# Mosfet Vgs-Qg graph

Tags: mosfet

[image]

What is the reason behind the horizontal region in the center? why gate-source voltage doesn't increase in that region, even though we are adding charges to it?

Comment: Because the huge delta-Voltage of the drain, and the attendant huge charge flows into the gate-drain capacitance, causes an apparent TOTAL flattening of the Gate voltage. But its not totally flat, just changing only by delta_drain_voltage / voltage_gain.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74867/relationship-between-the-gate-charge-graph-and-the-vgs-waveform?rq=1